# Использование Type переменной при преобразовании object в тип (object as ..)

Tags: c#

Есть переменная Type, в которую я заношу значение typeof(Какой-либо класс). При этом я получаю object (в примере это свойство Message какого-либо класса), который мне нужно преобразовать в класс, указанный в Type переменную. Как сделать это максимально лаконично?

```
Type type = typeof(FoundResponseMessage);

var o = message.Message as ...// как использовать type
```

Comment: Так не получится, Type это рантайм тип, его нельзя использовать для манимуляции типами на этапе компиляции. Так как вы хотите сделать нельзя. Вероятно вам смогут помочь обобщения, дженерики.

Comment: @aepot спасибо за пояснение

Comment: Используйте дженерики

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Типизация во время выполнения - очень сомнительная по нужности вещь.

Похоже на проблему XY. Что вы задумали? А что вы потом будете делать с переменной o?

В общем, есть четыре варианта (в зависимости от того, что вам нужно):

1. Дженерики.
2. Наследование и интерфейсы.
3. Если вы будете пользовать переменную `o`, то вы будете применять к ней в коде какие-то конкретные члены. В этом случае можно использовать приведение к типу dynamic, тогда связывание будет происходить на этапе выполнения:

```
var o = message.Message;
((dynamic)o).Amember();
```

4. Ну а в остальных случаях используйте рефлексию. Вот [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1536804/%D0%9E%D0%9E%D0%9F-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5/1536829#1536829) один из примеров, как можно что-то сделать.

**P. S.** Тогда используйте интерфейс. Сделайте интерфейс и сошлитесь на него в классах responseMessage и requestMessage, а переменную `o` объявите типом этого интерфейса.

```
public interface IMessage {
  Atype Amember();
}
class responseMessage : Message, IMessage {
  ...
  public Atype Amember() {
    ..
  }
}
class requestMessage: Message, IMessage {
  ...
  public Atype Amember() {
    ..
  }
}
...
IMessage o = message.Message;
o.Amember() ...
```

Comment: Изначально хотел использовать дженерики. Получаю от конечной точки API ответ в виде JSON, но при ответе у структуры может меняться только один блок:

1)
`...
"responseMessage" : "..."
...`

2)
`...
"requestMessage" : "..."
...`

Остальные блоки ответа не меняются